# Is "A Project Guide to UX Design" correct grammar?

Tags: meaning

> A Project Guide to UX Design.

This is the title of a book I got from Amazon. But I dont think the title makes sense. I did a Google search for the exact term "a project guide" and got very few results. Maybe a Project managers' guide, or a project guideline. UX stands for User Experience, by the way. But 'A project guide to' anything seems incorrect to me. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

A Project Guide to UX Design is, well, kind of just that.

It's a guide to how you might find User Experience Design (UX Design; it's not appearing to be up-to-date by using the acronym, it's a known, relatively common term in the industry at this point), and some of its artifacts, inserted into a project.

You could argue that it could have been "A Guide to Using User Experience Design in Your Projects", perhaps, and maybe that's a better translation. The title, itself, doesn't come from just the authors, there are all sorts of representatives from a publisher (including the marketing folks) who work hard to ensure a title "works". (I didn't say they always succeed, but as a publisher they also have technical and development editors who should be making sure it's grammatically correct!)

We're currently working on a second edition of the title--I'm glad you enjoyed it, Brian.

Comment: +1 for *there are all sorts of representatives from a publisher (including the marketing folks) who work hard to ensure a title "works"* -- a fact, and I entirely agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

It is, as was often written by my English teacher on my papers, "indolently elliptical".  I would read it as shorthand for "A project-oriented guide to user-centric design".  "User experience design" is ugly but I think he just wants to appear up to date by using the UX acronym.

Comment: I dont mind the UX design bit, that is now the accepted terminology. But thanks for the shorthand explanation - it was really bugging me. Great book though

Comment: Why is "user experience design" ugly?

Comment: I'm not up to date with UX and hadn't appreciated that "UX design" is an accepted term. I'm more used to terms like "user-centric design".  Since it's a book for a target market I accept that the target market's ability to resolve the terms trumps my parsing of it.  Since experience can be either a noun or a verb I find it's positioning sub-optimal in general terms.

Comment: I don't think most poeple would read *experience* in *user experience design* as a verb. For background: the parts that the user interacts with used to be called the UI ("User Interface") and the field used to be called "UI design", but (I guess) with an awareness that was being designed was the entire user's experience (workflow, etc.) and not just how windows should look, it's now called "user experience design".

Answer (score 0):

This is common usage, in terms of a noun modifying another noun, thus acting as an adjective.

You can read more here, if you so desire: http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/noun-as-adjective.html